# Clipboard data check and convert to text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `textarea` and when i paste a inside in it using `ctrl+v` , i need to check the content and if any content inside in it i need to change it into text and place it inside the `textarea`. any method by using `JavaScript` ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You cannot access the clipboard via javascript, but you can access data pasted into a textarea and change it before it actually get's placed.

Comment: i don't think it's possible with only javascripts.

Comment: @red-X. ok.how can i clear that data before pasting it in textarea.?